# Python Pandas MemoryError on first run, goes away on rerun

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory

I'm running a long Python program that includes a step of reading a file into a Pandas dataframe. The program consistently fails with a MemoryError when it first tries to read the file into memory. When I rerun the failing step (without rerunning the previous parts of the program), there is no MemoryError.

It may be a problem of accumulating lots of previous objects in memory, which aren't present on the rerun. But the amount of memory in play is below the 2 GB limit where Windows starts having problems. In particular, the previous steps of the program only leave around ~400 MB in RAM, and the file I'm trying to read takes only ~400 MB.

Any ideas what's causing the MemoryError the first time around?

Comment: That's unfortunate, but how can we help?

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone knows what causes the MemoryError so that I can keep it from happening the first time. It seems like there should be plenty of RAM left, but maybe there's some other factor that I'm missing besides the 2 GB limit for the size of a Windows object.

Comment: Windows should cope with objects larger than 2GB (on 64bit). In your case, does memory fragmentation occur?

Comment: It sounds like you're answering your own question.  The memory error is coming from the accumulation of previous objects most likely.  If possible use 64bit windows and a 64bit version of python and that will ensure you make the most of your computer's memory (which is presumably more than 2 GB).

Comment: Make sure the program doesn't keep references to data that's not used any more. Did you structure your code into functions?  Usually that's enough to prevent keeping unnecessary objects in memory.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

For now I'm using 32-bit Python out of concern that some libraries might not work with 64-bit, though I haven't tried that to see if it's the case.

The code does use functions, and most allocated objects get deallocated, though there is still ~400 MB left around in RAM for some reason.

@ChristianSauer: Fragmentation does sound like a plausible explanation. Are there ways to verify that?